# How to apply in Function<T, R> argument from List (not List)

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream, functional-interface

I have a method which returns company as key and list of employeer as values 
`<T> Map<String, List<T>> getUserPerCompany(final Function<User, T> converter)`.
The method accepts the `converter` parameter which in the tests returns the String (name + lastname of the employee). It should returns: `Map<String, List<String>>`. I created this implementation:

`return getUserStream().collect(toMap(Company::getName, c -> converter.apply(c.getUsers())));`

Error is:
`apply (domain.User) in Function cannot be applied to (java.util.List<domain.User>)`

My problem is that I do not know how to pass the employee to the 'apply' list instead of the list in full.

My other attempts:

- `return getUserStream().collect(toMap(Company::getName, c -> converter.apply((User) c.getUsers().listIterator())));`
- `return getUserStream().collect(toMap(Company::getName, c -> converter.apply((User) c.getUsers().subList(0, c.getUsers().size()))));`
- `return getUserStream().collect(toMap(Company::getName, c -> converter.apply((User) c.getUsers().iterator())));`

Comment: Not read the question but first n the title "from List (not List)" is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose this is what you're looking for

```
<T> Map<String, List<T>> getUserPerCompany(final Function<User, T> converter) {
    return getUserStream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
            c -> c.getName(),
            c -> c.getUsers()
                  .stream()
                  .map(converter)
                  .collect(Collectors.toList())
    ));
}
```

Usage example is

```
final Map<String, List<String>> users = getUserPerCompany(user -> user.getName() + " " + user.getSurname());
```

Basically you need to `map` each `User`, applying the input `Function`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have just replaced `getUserStream ()` with `getCompanyStream ()` (companies contain users) but these are my internal methods that are not here. Thank you again for the solution, it works and it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Collectors.groupingBy()` and write custom `Collector`:

```
<T> Map<String, List<T>> getUserPerCompany(final Function<User, T> converter) {
    return getUserStream().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                    c -> c.getName(),
                    Collector.of(
                            ArrayList::new,                  //init accumulator
                            (list, c)-> c.getUsers()         //processing each element
                                         .stream()
                                         .map(converter)
                                         .forEach(list::add),
                            (result1, result2) -> {          //confluence 2 accumulators 
                                result1.addAll(result2);     //in parallel execution
                                return result1;
                            }
                    )
            )
    ); 
}
```

Comment: `Stream` is lower than `fori` and `foreach`=> replace it use `for`